# What is the difference between instance variables in a class or using them as parameters in a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, class-instance-variables

How is using studentName and studentAverage different in the class or in the constructor?

```
public class StackOverFlowQ {

    String studentName;
    int studentAverage;


    public void StackOverFlowQ (String stedentName, int studentAverage){

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you have declared your constructor as a `void`. So it's actually treated as a method.

Comment: I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt with your constructor (constructors don't have return types *at all*), and the name of the parameter `stedentName`.  Mind coming back and fixing those?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1), and there's a specific case that applies to this situation.

> A declaration d of a field or formal parameter named n shadows, throughout the scope of d, the declarations of any other variables named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs.

To distill that a bit for you:

You have declared fields `studentName` and `studentAverage` as formal parameters in your constructor.  *In the scope of that constructor*, any references to the above two names will be treated as using the parameters, and no other higher level field.

If you need to refer to the field, then use the `this` keyword as if you were dereferencing the field.

```
this.studentName = studentName;
this.studentAverage = studentAverage;
```

There's a *huge* difference in usage not just in variable shadowing, but access as well.  On your constructor, you will only ever have the variables `studentName` and `studentAverage` available within the scope of it.  Someone that instantiates this class can't access the values in those parameters unless they're captured into fields.

Hence, the fields which are similarly named come into play.  Those fields, depending on their visibility or exposure through other methods, can actually be used by other classes.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, if you wish to reference the instance variables you must preface with `this`; otherwise you will be referencing the parameters.

For example:

```
public class StackOverFlowQ {

    String studentName;
    int studentAverage;


    public StackOverFlowQ (String studentName, int studentAverage){
        this.studentName = "Paul" // will point to the instance variable.
        studentName = "Paul"; // will point to the parameter in the constructor
    }
}
```